# How to save a 2 Dimensional array?

Tags: vb.net

I am making a 'Robot wars' type of code where the user can create, delete and search for characters and their stats. When I create a character I want to be able to use that character even after the program is closed. Is there any way to do this? I am just declaring the array in a private sub right now:

```
Dim characters(10,4) As String  
'name , attack , defense , health
Private Sub ExtractInfo()
    characters(1, 1) = "Terminus"
    characters(1, 2) = "72"
    characters(1, 3) = "14"
    characters(1, 4) = "200"
    characters(2, 1) = "Sir Kill-a-lot"
    characters(2, 2) = "60"
    characters(2, 3) = "30"
    characters(2, 4) = "250"
```

However I want the information both here and the information added to be saved for use even after the code stops running.

Comment: @muffi This question is about VB.NET not VBA

Comment: @MatSnow These two languages are not too far away. There should be no problem to use streams instead of files.

Comment: @muffi _not too far away_ means it's not the same. Means the proposed question is NOT a duplicate.

Comment: @muffi I will look at this thread and may delete this thread if I can get it to work.

Comment: Proposed dupe is barely related, except some words in the title and "VB".

Comment: This is no dupe for me neither....

Answer (score 2):

One way to save/load binary data is to use `Serialization`.
It´s easy to implement for non-complex object relations.

So basically you create a class and decorate it with the `<Serializable>` attribute. 
All (public) members will then be serialized/deserialized when you call the proper `BinaryFormatter.Serialize` or `BinaryFormatter.Deserialize` methods.

Example:

```
<Serializable>
    Public Class Characters
    Public characters(10, 4) As String
    Public Sub Save(path As String)
        serialize(path)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load(path As String) As Characters
        Return deSerialize(path)
    End Function

    Private Sub serialize(path As String)
        Try
            Using fs As Stream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
                bf.Serialize(fs, Me)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error handling
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function deSerialize(path As String) As Characters
        Try
            Using fs As Stream = New FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
                Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
                deSerialize = CType(bf.Deserialize(fs), Characters)
            End Using
            Return deSerialize
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Error handling
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
```

Usage:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a = New Characters()
    a.characters(0, 0) = "Stack"
    a.characters(0, 1) = "Overflow"
    a.characters(1, 0) = "Is"
    a.characters(1, 1) = "awesome!"

    a.Save("E:\characters.sav")

    Dim b = Characters.Load("E:\characters.sav")
    Console.WriteLine(b.characters(0, 0))
    '-> Stack
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```